# Python - Writing CSV formatted data to a CSV with a variable filename

Tags: python, csv

Python 3.6.

New to Python...first post be gentle...

I cant wrap my mind around this...
As described in the title, I have CSV formatted data that I need to write to a CSV file with a variable filename.

Currently my code creates the CSV with the appropriate filename, and writes data to the CSV, **but the data is 1 letter on each row**.

Code looks like:

```
import csv
filename = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + '\Downloads\Somefolder\\'+ variablefilename + '.csv'
myfile = open(filename, 'w', newline='')
     with myfile:
          writer = csv.writer(myfile)
          writer.writerows(csvformatteddata.decode('utf-8'))
#csvformatteddata was generated prior to this code.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, but I would like an explanation with the "solution" code if possible.

I am looking to learn/grow, not have my ignorance enabled.

Comment: Can you share the structure of your `csvformatteddata`?

Comment: @Jere Käpyaho - a,b,c\nd,e,f\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerows` is expecting an iterable of iterables containing the data for each row, with the `i`th element of the "inner" iterable being the contents of the `i`th column of the a. It looks like `csvformatteddata` is a single string. (I'm guessing it looks like `a,b,c\nd,e,f\n...`.)

To elaborate, the reason you're getting a single character on each line is that one long string is itself an iterable of iterables--iterate over a string and you get an individual character and iterate over that character to get that same character. Thus each character becomes a "row".

Comment: yes you are correct, it is a single string. Now what method can i use to write that string to the CSV. Also thank you for the explaination.

Comment: `myfile.write(csvformatteddata)` Also, it'd be more usual to write `with open(filename, 'w') as myfile: ...` However, the key point is that, unless you've been handed this giant string from somewhere, you don't have to (and don't want to!) manually format the CSV.

Comment: Once you have the precise string you want to write to a file, the fact it is a CSV is irrelevant, you're just writing to a file.

Comment: This explanation helped me understand what was happening and allowed me to correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: with open('text.csv', 'r') as old_file:
   ...:     with open('new.csv', 'w') as new_file:
   ...:         reader = csv.reader(old_file)
   ...:         writer = csv.writer(new_file)
   ...:         writer.writerows(reader)
   ...:

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is a single string, you should split it into rows as described in the `csv` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

If you constructed the string yourself, don't do that. Just let the CSV writer handle the delimiters and newlines.

So for `csv.writer` to do its thing your data should look like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

That way you should be able to write the CSV file just fine:

```
$ python3
>>> import csv
>>> csvformatteddata = [['a','b','c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>> myfile = open('test.csv', 'w')
>>> writer = csv.writer(myfile)
>>> writer.writerows(csvformatteddata)
>>> myfile.close()
^D
$ cat test.csv
a,b,c
d,e,f
```